# How does staging a file modify the index file internally?

Tags: git, git-index, git-stage

git index(.git/index) stores the state of tracked files (last committed state) and it can be shown via git ls-files --stage and `git diff` looks at the difference between index and working directory.  How does the use of `git add` to stage files modify index file internally?